# MFC floating toolbar always active

Tags: c++, mfc, toolbar, floating, always-on-top

I' m new with MFC. I needed to create a floating toolbar (CToolBar) with no option of docking and save and restore its last pos.

The toolbar also should be active all the time, but its NOT.
When I'm openning a new child window (dialog for instance) from the mainframe, the floating tool bar become not active (I can not click on its buttons, or drag it etc..).

In the past I've used CDiaolog with Overlapped style and it was floating and always active as I needed. Is it possible to do the same with my Floating Toolbar? Thanks

```
int CMainFrame::OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct)
{     
   if (CFrameWnd::OnCreate(lpCreateStruct) == -1)
   return -1;

   toolbarIconSize.cx = toolbarIconSize.cy = TOOLBAR_MAIN_ICON_SIZE;
   if ( !m_wndMyFloatingToolbar.Create(this,m_wndMyFloatingToolbar.GetBarStyle() |WS_EX_PALETTEWINDOW  | WS_EX_TOPMOST  |CBRS_FLOATING | WS_VISIBLE) ||
    !m_wndMyFloatingToolbar.LoadToolBar(IDR_GENERAL_TOOLBAR, toolbarIconSize))
    {
       TRACE0("Failed to create My Floating Toolbar\n");
       return -1;      // fail to create
    }

   m_wndMyFloatingToolbar.EnableDocking(0);
   EnableDocking(0);

   if (!CreateCtrlBar())
   {
       TRACE0("Failed to create ctrl toolbar\n");
       return -1;      // fail to create
   }

   // ...
   //...
   return 0; 
}

void CMainFrame::OnViewToolBar()
{
   // ...
   //...

   CPoint Pos = MyFloatingToolbarGetLastPosition(); \\Get last pos 
   FloatControlBar( &m_wndMyFloatingToolbar, Pos, CBRS_ALIGN_LEFT );
   MyFloatingToolbarSetIsVisible();
   FloatControlBar( &m_wndMyFloatingToolbar, Pos, CBRS_ALIGN_LEFT );
}
void CMainFrame::MyFloatingToolbarSetIsVisible()
{
   WINDOWPLACEMENT wp;
   m_wndMyFloatingToolbar.GetParent()->GetParent()->GetWindowPlacement(&wp);
   wp.showCmd = SW_SHOW;
   m_wndMyFloatingToolbar.GetParent()->GetParent()->SetWindowPlacement(&wp);

   m_wndMyFloatingToolbar.GetParent()->GetWindowPlacement(&wp);
   wp.showCmd = SW_SHOW;
   m_wndMyFloatingToolbar.GetParent()->SetWindowPlacement(&wp);

   m_wndMyFloatingToolbar.GetWindowPlacement(&wp);
   wp.showCmd = SW_SHOW;
   m_wndMyFloatingToolbar.SetWindowPlacement(&wp);
}
void CWJToolBar::OnWindowPosChanging(WINDOWPOS FAR* lpwndpos)
{ 
   CToolBar::OnWindowPosChanging(lpwndpos); 

   if ( GetBarStyle() & CBRS_FLOATING )
   {
       if((lpwndpos->flags & SWP_HIDEWINDOW) && ((this->GetParentFrame())->m_hWnd !=(this->GetTopLevelFrame())->m_hWnd)) 
       { 
           CMainFrame* mf = (CMainFrame*)(AfxGetApp()->GetMainWnd());
           mf->MyFloatingToolbarSavePosition();         
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: You should probably convert x and y to screen coordinates using ClientToScreen function either before you store them or after reading them from file.

Comment: Why don't you use CMFCToolbar?

Answer (score 1):

1. You may need to debug to view its coordinates if they are correctly set. Be independent. :p
2. Based on your current posted code, I don't see the point of your stored data, try this

   - hiding your toolbar
   - saving its position data
   - changing your parent windows position and
   - reloading your saved coordinates.

The saved data becomes incorrect values then.

I suggest you capture the position to which you want to add your toolbar  *live* . This makes your toolbar application more generic.
So,

1. Save your toolbar's i.e top-left distance to its parent windows, not its coordinates
2. Get your parent windows coordinates
3. Reload your toolbar based on the saved distance

There are of course other ways to do this but I think this is more trivial to accomplish what you may be looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Use CMFCToolBar (instead CToolBar), then you need only 2 commands, to achieve this.

```
int CMainFrame::OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct)
{
  if (CMDIFrameWndEx::OnCreate(lpCreateStruct) == -1)
     return -1;

    :
    m_wndToolBar.SetPermament(TRUE);   // it removes CloseButton (=always active)

    CRect rect;
    GetClientRect(&rect);
    ClientToScreen(rect);
    rect.OffsetRect(100, 20);
    m_wndToolBar.FloatPane(rect);      // Float and move it to your wished coordinates
    :

}
```